# NextConnect use a middleware inside another

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, next-connect

I have an auth middleware that I want to use it's logic to develop other middlewares (ie: adminMiddleware, receptionMiddleware ...)

```js
// adminMiddleware.ts
const authMiddleware = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  next: NextHandler
) => {
   // logic to check authentication status
  (req as NextApiRequestWithSession).session = obj;
  next();
};
```

I wrote the code below but I don't think it would work or if it's the best solution:

```js
const adminMiddleware = (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  next: NextHandler
) =>
  nc()
    .use(authMiddleware, async (req: NextApiRequestWithSession, res, next) => {
      // check if the auth user is an admin
      return next();
    }) as NextConnect<NextApiRequestWithUser, NextApiResponse>;
export default adminMiddleware;
```